# How can I create a singelton value in a module?

Tags: haskell

I have a type as follows:

```
data Stitch mark = OverStitch mark (Stitch mark) | TokenStitch | TerminalStitch
```

There can only be one single value of TerminalStitch. So I wish I could define this value at the top level of my module something like that:

```
terminalStitch :: Stitch
terminalStitch = TerminalStitch -- <--- value = constructor()
```

But it doesn't seem to work. What should I do instead?

Comment: There are at least a couple of problems.  `terminalStitch` has type `Stitch a`, not `Stitch` or `TerminalStitch`.  Also, you have a spelling typo in the second line of your `terminalStitch` declaration.

Comment: fixed the typo, `Stitch a` has helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the concrete problem here is a typo

```
terminalSticth = TerminalStitch
--         ^ swapped the letters
```

Also in your type signature, you need to provide stitch a type

```
terminalStitch :: Stitch a
```

What are you trying to achieve here? In Haskell you can't compare things "by identity" only by value. So using `terminalStitch` is completely identical to just using `TerminalStitch`.

Comment: I am trying to get a constant that would always match to `TerminalStitch`. A TerminalSitch for Stitch is the same as 0 for Integer.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov Than why not just use `TerminalStitch`? I mean you can do this if you want, but I don't see the point

Comment: That's exactly what I did, didn't I?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov I mean, why make a constant `terminalStitch` when you already have the perfectly good constant `TerminalStitch`. I don't see the point of adding this additional name since it provides no new information or semantics, it's just kinda there

Comment: That's a good question. I didn't realize that a constructor is the same as a value. I am from OO, where we separate types from values. So to me TerminalStitch is a type and `terminalStitch = TerminalStich -- instantiating the TerinalStitch` is a value. I seems I was wrong about it.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov Constructor doesn't mean the same as in OO, if you check the type of `TerminalStitch` you'll find that it's just `Stitch a`, a constructor `Bar = .. | ... | .. | Foo A B C`  is just a function of type `A -> B -> C -> Bar`